# CakePHP makes a join between two models, but not between two others

Tags: cakephp

I have four very simple models. Offer, Employer, Employee and Response.

```
Offer hasOne Employer
Employer hasMany Offer
Response hasOne Employee
Employee hasMany Offer
```

And now when I make a `find()` on `Offer`, it nicely makes a JOIN query and returns Employer details.

But when I make a `find()` on `Response`, it doesn't attempt to retrieve Employee's data.

I reviewed the code many times, stripped the models off of any additional properties etc., and still nothing. Those models are now nearly identical, their SQL tables too, but Response behaves like it has no relation to Employee defined.

Any pitfall with this that I might be trapped in?  I'm ready to report this as a bug at this moment.

I can post complete (which are short, anyway) model definitions here if it helps anything.

Comment: I'm wondering if this relation is setup properly; Response hasOne Employee and Employee hasMany Offer? Shouldn't that be Response **`belongsTo`** Employee??

Comment: please post your find code as well as which model or controller it's in and what the current level of recursive is.

Comment: Of course, Response belongsTo Employee, just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

### Check the class of your model instances

I.e.

```
debug(get_class($this->Response));
```

If it outputs `AppModel` - the reason your code doesn't appear to be being used, is because: it isn't being used. That being the case, check for typos in the filename/location of your model files - as CakePHP will silently use an AppModel instance if your model files don't exist.

Comment: Bull's eye. It returns "AppModel" indeed. After a detailed search I found a typo in Responses model filename - 'Reponses'. Thanks for help. Anyway, this 'assumption' feature is cool only if you use it intentionally. Is there any option to pop up some warning in case of such a typo etc.?

Comment: You probably are using it intentionally in other use cases - e.g. join models for habtm relationships. There's nothing to turn this off in the core, you can use something like this if you like: https://gist.github.com/AD7six/659715af1699ab0569fe